# eth: error fetching interface information: Device not found

Tags: ubuntu, ifconfig, interface

I have an ubuntu 18.04 linux server.

Why does the command(`ifconfig eth`) says Device not found whereas this command(`ifconfig eth0`) works?

```
$ ifconfig eth

eth: error fetching interface information: Device not found


$ ifconfig eth0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 96.114.208.69  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 
        96.114.208.127
        inet6 fe80::8a9:12ff:fe5b:c324  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:a9:12:5b:c3:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5126229  bytes 7622036755 (7.6 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1823543  bytes 124228703 (124.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note: I tried the same thing on my other 14.04 linux server. Both commands are working

Comment: Post the output from the working system

Answer (score 2):

Because you don' t have any `eth` device, but you have the `eth0`.
If you use `ifconfig -a` or `ip addr` you can see all the devices available.

Comment: on ubuntu 14.04 server, both commands returns same output

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-96-114-208-17:~$ ifconfig eth
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:c6:8c:f3:88:84  
          inet addr:96.114.208.17  Bcast:96.114.208.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c6:8cff:fef3:8884/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:3073083 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17790249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:628310363 (628.3 MB)  TX bytes:25682765383 (25.6 GB)`

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-96-114-208-17:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:c6:8c:f3:88:84  
          inet addr:96.114.208.17  Bcast:96.114.208.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c6:8cff:fef3:8884/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:3073247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17792171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:628338790 (628.3 MB)  TX bytes:25685051888 (25.6 GB)`

Comment: In the question you said that the output is different and that you are using ubuntu 18.04 server and not the 14.04. What is the output of `ifconfig -a` ?

Comment: @Nani it's probably a good idea to omit your public IP address from your PS1 (since it contains your IP) and the output of ifconfig. Also formatting in a comment can be difficult to read, so you would likely get a better response if you're to amend your question with those outputs rather than in the comments :)